# Namespace error in my module.php in ZF2

Tags: php, namespaces, zend-framework2

Error :

```
Fatal error: Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement in the script in C:\xampp\htdocs\zf2-tutorial\module\Album\Module.php on line 8
```

Module.php

```
<?php

namespace Application;

use Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

class Module
{
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
    $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
}

public function getConfig()
{
    return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
}

public function getAutoloaderConfig()
{
    return array(
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
            'namespaces' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
            ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

I've already checked for white spaces and as you can see namespace declaration is first after the opening php tag. Can't figure out what's causing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error is telling you that there are any output before the [namespace declaration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

Look for whitespaces before `<?php` in your files. This could be caused by some editors adding [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) to UTF8 files, so you should save them as *"UTF8 without BOM"* or *"Unicode"*.

Comment: I'll try the unicode thing to see if this fixes it , in my current IDE I've checked for white spaces.

Comment: I've saved it with UTF8 without BOM, and it still outputs this error. The only thing that changes is the line in which the error appears (line 3)

Comment: Are you using Windows? What IDE are you using? The output could be in another file that includes the Module class.

Comment: Yes , that was the problem , I was looking in the module.php for application and it was from a another module.